# strawberry perl module installation undefined reference

Tags: perl, module, undefined-reference

I am running Windows7 and Strawberry Perl 5.26.0.1
I try to install:

> cpan Math::Random::MTwist

```
    "C:\Perl64\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Mksymlists \
     -e "Mksymlists('NAME'=>\"Math::Random::MTwist\", 'DLBASE' => 'MTwist', 'DL_FUNCS' => {  }, 'FUNCLIST' => [], 'IMPORTS' => {  }, 'DL_VARS' => []);"
g++ MTwist.def -o blib\arch\auto\Math\Random\MTwist\MTwist.xs.dll -mdll -s -L"C:\Perl64\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\Perl64\STRAWB~1\c\lib" MTwist.o   "C:\Perl64\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\libperl526.a" -lmoldname -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lnetapi32 -luuid -lws2_32 -lmpr -lwinmm -lversion -lodbc32 -lodbccp32 -lcomctl32 -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base
MTwist.o:MTwist.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `_imp__Perl_get_context'
MTwist.o:MTwist.c:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `_imp__Perl_sv_2pv_flags'
...

MTwist.o:MTwist.c:(.text+0x6ce2): undefined reference to `_imp__Perl_xs_boot_epilog'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake: *** [Makefile:490: blib\arch\auto\Math\Random\MTwist\MTwist.xs.dll] Error 1
-> FAIL Installing Math::Random::MTwist failed. See C:\Users\mschmidt\.cpanm\work\1500562766.20452\build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

Any ideas what goes wrong?

Comment: tried both cpan and cpanm. 
Installed under strawverry perl: C:\Perl64\strawberry\perl\bin

Comment: perl references on PATH are: C:\Perl64\strawberry\c\bin;C:\Perl64\strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Perl64\strawberry\perl\bin

Comment: no other perl installations

Comment: cpanm Statistics::Basic

Comment: the stats package builds and install fine.

Comment: Is it using the right compiler? The filename is MTwist.c, but it's using a C++ compiler. C and C++ are similar, but different languages and use different naming schemes for their symbol tables.

Comment: @Chris Turner, That's not it. SP uses `gcc` for compiling and `g++` for linking. I don't know it's done that way, but it hasn't prevented Math::Random::MTwist from being compiled by [others](http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/1e71f4c2-8dfe-1014-9266-30ed5f496936). (See `cc='gcc'` and `ld='g++'` in the config of that successful install.)

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add information instead of putting it into comments.

Comment: Is the version of MTwist the same as in that report? Assuming all the libraries mentioned exist, it could be needing a newer version of one of the dependencies if it's a more recent version